# Performance-wise, is it better to add many columns or many rows?

Tags: sql, h2

The table I'm building will have around 8M records. This information can either be stored "vertically" (in rows) or "horizontally" (in columns), based on the type of data I am dealing with.

In terms of performance, how should I build this table ? I've ran preliminary tests on a table with 74 rows, 43200 columns (3.2M "data points") and the response time is really rough. 13 seconds are necessary to retrieve 1 row, and retrieving the entire table consistently crashes the H2 web interface.

Should I expect to encounter this same issue with a table of 3.2M rows ?

Thanks.

Comment: The tests were performed without an index. I am currently running the same tests with an index.

Comment: Without knowing the nature of the queries and the data and what is in the columns, there is not enough information to provide a useful answer to a specific question.  But, 3.2 million rows is not considered a particularly big table nowadays.

Comment: The data would be timestamps and a boolean most likely, or BIG INTs if I just use a Unix timestamp as an integer. The queries would mainly be `SELECT * FROM Component WHERE component_host_name='some name'` , but also `UPDATE`. As time goes on, I will need to basically shift all timestamp values one to the left if using columns (since they correspond to the next 30 days). Sorry if it's all a bit blurry, I'm still figuring things out as I go. Ignore the last part about shifting actually, I'll just be changing the boolean value.

Comment: Please include some examples of the two options. In general terms, if your query is covered by an index, it will be fast with many millions of rows; if it can't use an index, it will be slower - how much slower depends very heavily on the query and the table layout.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rows. RDBMS are built to store large amounts of data and they will be easier to understand and read with many rows and few columns